# Assign string to NvAPI_UnicodeString

Tags: c, unicode, nvapi

Now I'm working on NVAPI.

There is a type "NvAPI_UnicodeString".

It is a unsigned short array.

```
typedef NvU16 NvAPI_UnicodeString[NVAPI_UNICODE_STRING_MAX];
typedef unsigned short   NvU16;
```

and there is a type "NvAPI_LPCWSTR", also.

```
typedef const NvU16 *NvAPI_LPCWSTR;
```

I want assign a value to NvAPI_UnicodeString like

```
NvAPI_UnicodeString = L"Hello";
```

But it doesn't work.

Please let me know how to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign an array using the = operator.
You have to use memcpy or memcpy_s

```
NvAPI_UnicodeString wsz;
memcpy_s(wsz, sizeof(wsz), L"Hello", 6*sizeof(wchar_t));
```